# airflow install fails when using pipenv

Tags: airflow, pipenv

I'm trying to install python package airflow into a virtualenv that has been created using pipenv, inside a docker container. It fails with an error that I'm clueless about.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

WORKDIR /tmp

# Define build args
ARG http_proxy
ARG https_proxy
ARG no_proxy

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install default-jdk

# Detect JAVA_HOME and export in bashrc.
# This will result in something like this being added to /etc/bash.bashrc
#   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
RUN echo export JAVA_HOME="$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:/jre/bin/java::")" >> /etc/bash.bashrc

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install core python packages
RUN pip install pipenv==2018.5.18
```

Build and run:
`docker build -t pipenvtest:latest .`
`docker run -it pipenvtest:latest bash`

When connected to the container:
`pipenv --python 2.7`
`pipenv install --dev airflow`

Which fails with this error:

> building '_yaml' extension
>      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ext
>      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ext/_yaml.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ext/_yaml.o
>      ext/_yaml.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>       #include "Python.h"
>                          ^
>      compilation terminated.
>      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

(the ^ actually appears at the end of the line preceding it but I don't know how to format the quoted text as such)

I admit to not having the faintest idea how to go about solving this so hoping someone can give me some pointers. I hope the repro that I've included here works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was being really dumb. I was trying to setup a python2.7 virtualenv on an image built from python:3.6-stretch.

I changed

`pipenv --python 2.7`

to

`pipenv --python 3.6`

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `--dev` switch in `pipenv install --dev airflow` intended? It instructs `pipenv` to install development dependencies of Airflow too. One of these dependencies needs the `Python.h` header file (which is missing). To resolve the problem:

- If you do not need the development dependencies then
  remove the `--dev` switch.
- If you need the development
  dependencies then install the `libpython2.7-dev` package, which
  provides `Pthon.h`, before you install Aiflow: `apt install libpython2.7-dev`

Comment: thanks for the reply @sergiykolesnikov. Your reply was very useful to me however the problem was actually a cause of my own stupidity. See my answer.